# Microsoft Graph API for Email Attachment can't filter by Size

Tags: url, microsoft-graph-api, odata

I'm using the API documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-list-attachments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

I'm also using a couple of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters, including $select, which works fine and $filter, which does not

I'm looking to filter Attachments by size, like this

`...URL...?$select=field1,field2,field3&$filter=size ge 1000`

But it seems to be ignored; I was testing this in Graph Explorer; I'm aware you can't have spaces in a URL, I used %20 instead, spaces used above for clarity

I tried one or two other filter parameters, which were OK; am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 0):

It's known issue that `attachments` endpoint does not support filters.

The `$filter` parameter is ignored.

Workaround is to filter attachments by size on the client.

Resources:

[Known issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#some-limitations-apply-to-query-parameters)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out; my User Case is that this data is going into a staging table so is easy to apply filter on update to main table; it's just that filtering on the API would lighten the load a little ...